# paint2 elemnets at sa,e random color

Tags: javascript

I have following code snippest
How would you paint the cards(I need to paint 2 cards at same random color)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    grid.innerHTML += '<div onclick="go(this)" class="card"></div> ';


}

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

const paintCards = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 2)
    {
        console.log(cards.style.backgroundColor)
        cards.style.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor();
        
    }


};
paintCards();
```

I did it with array of 25 random colors but I need to do it without it

Comment: ```function getRandomColor() {
  const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}```

Comment: thanks , I already have function to paint randomly
in paint cards I need to paint each 2 cards at same random color(its a memory game)

Answer (score 0):

In for loop, step of 2 is being used hence you may use `i` & `i+1` inside the body of the loop.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('#main');
for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
  grid.innerHTML += '<div onclick="go(this)" class="card"></div> ';
}

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const paintCards = () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 2) {
    const color = generateRandomColor();
    cards[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    cards[i + 1].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
};
paintCards();

function generateRandomColor() {
  const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: thanks but It doesnt work , it genertates random color to each of the 50 cards

Comment: Is this version helpful?

Comment: Yes , thanks
But I need somehow to paint them when they are created and the cards need to  be painted randomly to be 2 cards at same color somewhere in the array(not cards next to each other at same color )

Answer (score 0):

UPD: Added an array to keep the randomized colors in it. Once we empty it - let's fill it again. I've used small pool size - e.g. 5 so we would get somehow randomized values. But this soultion is not the best - the distribution for elements that in border of beginning and end of the array would be different. But by this we would guarantee that cards would be colored in pairs. Also added initial painting for the main loop itself. Doing it as inline style. Hope that helps

Hey if I got your right - then you need to generate rnd color and keep it,
then paint two of cards into different color. Painting stuff depends on your req. Now I did paint of current and it's neighbour,and then move to the next i+2. We could simply paint every odd or even, etc. Hope that helps

```js
let grid = {innerHTML:''};
//we would fill this array dynamically
let randomColors = [];
const sizeOfRandomColors = 5;
let useRandomColors = false
// main idea here - keep 5 random colors, pick them randomly
// in case we filled colors - lets reuse them
// otherwise generate them

    function generateRandomColor() {
        let hexColorRep = "#";
        const hexChars= '0123456789ABCDEF';

        for (let index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
            const randomPosition = Math.floor ( Math.random() * hexChars.length ); 
            hexColorRep += hexChars[randomPosition];
        }
        
        return hexColorRep;
    }
    function getPairedColor() {
        let color = '';
        if (!useRandomColors) {
            color = generateRandomColor();
            randomColors.push(color);
            if (randomColors.length === sizeOfRandomColors) useRandomColors = true;
        } else if (useRandomColors) {
            const randomPosition = Math.floor ( Math.random() * randomColors.length );
            color = randomColors[randomPosition] || '#fff';
            randomColors = randomColors.slice(0,randomPosition).concat(randomColors.slice(randomPosition+1));
            if (randomColors.length === 0) useRandomColors = false;
        }
        
        return color;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        const rndColor = getPairedColor();
        grid.innerHTML += `<div onclick="go(this)" class="card" style="backgroundColor:${rndColor}">${i}</div> `;
    }

console.log(grid.innerHTML)
```

Comment: thanks
how would you do it when I create the cards?
and I need to paint the cards in random order not one next to each other

Comment: somebody can help please?

Comment: @אריפיין please check updated version